# Landingpage CSS

Tags: marketing-cloud, css, landing-page, css3

I created a Cloudpage and reference an external CSS file, everything is looking fine when opening the URL.

However, within the MC Landingpage editor the css file doesn't seem to get loaded, so the whole html is unstyled. Is there a way to get it loaded within the editor?

Comment: This would occur if you are using mixed content. For example, the CloudPage uses HTTPS but your external CSS file or an image URL within it is HTTP. Is the case for you?

Answer (score 1):

For landing pages best practice is to import your CSS as content. External CSS works fine for email but glitchy on landing pages.

To get the link for your uploaded CSS file, navigate to your content portfolio, select it. On the far right there is a downwards facing arrow click on it and select properties. URL will be beneath description.

Comment: Can you explain that bit more detailed, how to exactly do it? When uploading it internally will it be rendered within the editor?

Comment: Will do when I get to a desktop:)

Comment: I'm asking to use the css in landingpages. I'm able to upload the css files within content builder, but not able to get a url to the file. Normally when uploading images to content builder you get the url by clicking on the file. How do I get the URL for css files?

Comment: updated my answer @MichaelH

Comment: Unfortunetly there is no URL. See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8EaG.png

Comment: Have you been able to sort this out? Curious as to why this didnt work. Please share what worked

Comment: unfortunately not yet

Comment: Raise a support ticket seems strange